# Design pattern for ensuring the "signature" of generic lists is equal

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics

I have an interface, `Attribute`, that is going to be implemented in various ways,

```
class AttributeA implements Attribute{\\..}
class AttributeB implements Attribute{\\..}
```

Then I'm planning to have a class containing a list of interface members

```
class Example { 
    List<Attribute> attributes;
    //..
}
```

And then I'm planning to have a class containing a list of those

```
class ExamplesAndMore { 
    List<Example> examples;
    //..
}
```

But, I want any instatiation of `ExamplesAndMore` to make sure that it only takes examples of the same type or signature. That is, I want to make sure the `examples` list doesn' t contain one member whose `attributes` list is of the form `<AttributeA, AttributeA, AttributeB>` while another is of the `<AttributeA, AttributeA, AttributeA>` or `<AttributeA, AttributeA, AttributeB, AttributeB>`.

I could just check everywhere I modify the `examples` list.

A comment asked me to be more specific, so I'll give code for how I could do this.

```
class Example { 
    List<Attribute> attributes;

    public List<Class<? extends Attribute>> getSignature(){
        List<Class<? extends Attribute>> result = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Attribute>>();
        for(Attribute attribute : attributes){
            result.add(attribute.getClass());
        }

        return result;
    }

    //..
}

public class ExamplesAndMore {
    List<Example> examples;
    List<Class<? extends Attribute>> signature;

    public ExamplesAndMore(List<Class<? extends Attribute>> signature){
        this.signature = signature;
        this.examples = new ArrayList<Example>();
    }

    public void addExample(Example example){
        if(!example.getSignature().equals(signature)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("This takes examples with signature %s", signature.toString()));
        }
        examples.add(example);
    }

    //..
}
```

But I wonder if this is a good way of going about this, checking for types at runtime doesn't feel nice. Basically I think this code smells a bit. One way this smell might manifest as an actual problem is when I create

```
class GenericAttribute<T> implements Attribute{\\..}
```

with the intention of not having an example with an attribute of type `GenericAttribute<ClassA>` and one of type `GenericAttribute<ClassB>` in the same list. Then type erasure ruins my day.

Also, when I don't need examples to contain arbitrarily many attributes but only a fixed number (say 3), then my problem goes away entirely and I can even check at compile-time by having

```
class Example<T1, T2, T3> { 
    //..
}

public class ExamplesAndMore<T1,T2,T3> {
    List<Example<T1,T2,T3> examples;

    public void addExample(Example<T1,T2,T3> example){\\..}
    //..
}
```

However this approach obviously doesn't extend to examples with arbitrarily many attributes.

Anyway, I feel that I'm missing some obvious technique or something. Is there a nice pattern that deals with this, am I designing this badly? Chances are I'm not the first one doing this.

Also sorry for the lousy title, If I had a better description for my problem I'd probably have better luck searching for an answer and wouldn't have to ask...

Comment: Instead of worrying about "what design pattern", focus your question on the specific problem you have (or don't have).  Design patterns are just another tool to simplify communicating what a section of code does.  Not everything needs to be labeled as a design pattern.

Comment: @GlenH7 "Design patterns are just another tool to simplify communicating what a section of code does." I agree but I'd also add that they are also common consensus good ways of solving a specific problem. I figured a well known one might be applicable here. I can and will implement my "could just check everywhere" solution and edit my question. Maybe that makes it  a better question? If not, any other advice as to how to ask a "how do I do this in a nice structural way"-question? Are they just not appreciated here?

Comment: Looking for a pattern instead of solving the problem is a fool's errand.  Please [edit] your question to focus on the _specific problem_ you have with your code, and you are more likely to receive a meaningful answer.  You've already laid out most of your real problem in your previous comment.  Use that as the base and explain what's not working for you currently.

Comment: @GlenH7 So... I edited in my "could just check everywhere"-solution and edited the question to reflect that. But I somehow wonder if that made it a better question. I'm still just asking "is this a good way of going about things", there is nothing that is not working (as far as I can tell). That's because my question is not of that type. I understand your critique that is based in "Ask specific problems, because those are well suited for Q&A". But I also think you can see what my question is and see that it is just not that specific.

Comment: Why do you need those elements of the lists to be of the same types and lengths?

Answer (score 2):

It seems slightly odd that `Example.attributes` can contain a mixture of `AttributeA` and `AttributeB` objects, but `ExamplesAndMore.examples` must contain a 'homogenous' (using that loosely) `List` of `Example` objects. How are these supposed to be used, for both `Example` and `ExamplesAndMore` classes? Is there also some kind of implied ordering/equivalence between the entries of `ExamplesAndMore.examples`? Could *that* be another code-smell?

Staying on topic though, you may want a method inside `Example` that can reasonably describe the contents of itself... this can be as simple as concatenating the class names of its own entries, as illustrated below. I think that is safe enough since `List` have a predictable iteration order.

```
public String getEntriesDescription() {
    return attributes.stream().map(v -> v.getClass().getName())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
}
```

When you are adding an `Example` object to `ExamplesAndMore`, you can use that to perform the comparison you want...

```
public void addExample(Example example) {
    // assuming you have a field exampleDescription
    if (!exampleDescription.equals(example.getEntriesDescription()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Example description does not match.");
    }
    examples.add(example);
}
```

This is quite similar to what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If `class AttributeA` implements `Attribute` and `class AttributeB` implements the same, that means: *in some respect `AttributeA` behaves like `AttributeB`; and the abstraction level on which they do that, is behaving like `Attribute`*.
This is how polymorphism works!

> But, I want any instatiation of ExamplesAndMore to make sure that it only takes examples of the same type or signature.

The correct way of implementing this - according to your initial design would be to have a separate class of `Example` which has a List of Attributes of one kind, i.e. you need another `Interface` for `Example` which allows to distinguish between `Example containing AttributeA` and `Example containing AttributeB`. Then you are a) sure, that the concrete `Example` contains only the attributes you wanted and b) could use the abstraction of the interface to treat them the same in this respect.

In the end, you could define your `ExamplesAndMore` class, like intended: containing `Examples`, but not classes, but rather interfaces.